# Add line numbering in paragraphs

Tags: javascript, css, html, mustache

I am developing a web application in which I have to print a paragraph with every 5th line numbered according to line number

```
    I am living in New Jersey
2   who like to study music 
    create new applications
4   which can help others.
```

I am unable to write the html/css code for this.

I am using ajax request to extract paragraph data line by line and Mustache.js to render the data

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: add the line number to all lines, then hide most of them using CSS `:nth-child`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a bit more context here. Mostly the HTML structure you're dealing with.
Most of all, it may be interesting to know how your `<p>` tags and structured, how line returns are done (`<br/>`?)
This answer is a bit quick & dirty, but works.
The good thing is that there is no need to add a `<p>` tag for each line (as this would not make much sense).
The bad thing is it uses `<li>` tag without any reason, nor `<ul>` parent except to add automatically number through css

So please, do not consider this answer as a final solution, but just as a start

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <li>I am living in New Jersey</li><br/>
    <li>who like to study music</li><br/>
    <li>create new applications</li><br/>
    <li>which can help others.</li><br/>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
li:nth-of-type(even) {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
li:nth-of-type(odd) {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check this out bro http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/8necedtu/1/

```
         p:nth-child(odd) span {
           display:none;
               }
```

Comment: Then he'd still have to manually add those numbers, only to remove most of them afterwards with css.

Comment: Your answer is not proper please check it once...I have visited your jsfiddle link.